# Proof for $\forall x A(x) \Leftrightarrow \neg \exists x \neg A(x)$

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I try to proof, that $\forall x A(x) \Leftrightarrow \neg \exists x \neg A(x)$

I know how to prove, that $\forall x A(x) \Rightarrow \exists xA(x)$, but I don't understand how to get negation.

Comment: The statement $\forall x A \Leftrightarrow \exists xA$ is incorrect.

Comment: Also, you probably mean $\neg \exists x \neg A$.

Comment: Yeah, I did typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\forall x A(x) \equiv \forall x \lnot\lnot A(x) \equiv \lnot \exists x \lnot A(x)$$

Perhaps it makes more sense to you if we start from the right, and move to the left.

You'll need to remember that $$\lnot \forall x P(x) \equiv \exists x \lnot P(x)$$ and $$ \lnot \exists x P(x) \equiv \forall x \lnot P(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

A proof by words.

$\forall x A(X) \implies \lnot(\exists x \lnot A(x))$

$\forall x A(x)$ means that for every $x$ in the domain, the proposition $A(x)$ is true. This means that no $x$ exists such that $A(x)$ is false. Which can be written $\lnot (\exists x \lnot A(X))$, because the statement $\exists x \lnot A(X)$ always evaluates as false.

$\lnot(\exists x \lnot A(x)) \implies \forall x A(X)$

There is no $x$ such that $A(x)$ is false. Therefore on the domain of $x$, all $x$ imply $A(x)$ is true.

Small addendum: I think $\lnot(\exists x \lnot A(x))\equiv (\lnot\exists) x \lnot A(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one can use [conversion of quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)#Equivalent_expressions) (CQ) the following would be a way to show the biconditional using a Fitch-style proof checker.

[image]

See Chapter 34 in the [*forallx* text](http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf) for conversion of quantifiers. Two of these conversion rules are derived in Chapter 36.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: Avoid using a Conversion of Quantifier equivalence to prove a Conversion of Quantifiers equivalence:$$\def\ftch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\def\scope#1{\!\!\begin{array}{|l}#1\end{array}}\scope{~~~\vdots\\\ftch{~~8.~\neg\exists x~\neg A(x)}{\scope{\ftch{~~9.~\neg A(a)}{10.~\exists x~\neg A(x)\hspace{11ex}\exists\mathrm I~9\\11.~\bot\hspace{19ex}\neg\mathrm E~8,10}\\12.~A(a)\hspace{20ex}\mathrm {IP}~9{-}11}\\13.~\forall x~A(x)\hspace{17ex}\forall\mathrm I~12}\\14.~\forall x~A(x)\leftrightarrow\neg\exists x~\neg A(x)\hspace{5ex}{\leftrightarrow}\mathrm I~1{-}7,8{-}13}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Good use of existential introduction on your lines 9 and 10. I agree that I should have done something like that rather than using conversion of quantifiers.